# Unable to set php_value in .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, fastcgi, spawn-fcgi

I am trying to set up NewRelic on my Apache2/PHP server, and have it report different applications per vhost. To do this, the php value `newrelic.appname` must be changed. It is defined by default in `/etc/php.d/newrelic.ini` however to do per vhost reporting, it needs to be set specifically on that vhost, as described here: https://newrelic.com/docs/php/per-directory-settings

In my `/etc/php.d/newrelic.ini` is set:

```
newrelic.appname="PHP Application;MySite.com;"
```

In my vhost I have the following configuration:

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
    php_value newrelic.appname "MySite.com"
</Directory>
```

And it my `.htaccess` I have:

```
php_value newrelic.appname 'MySite.com'
```

But looking at `phpinfo()` served from a file in the same directory as the `.htaccess` file I get:

```
 Directive Name     Local/Active Value  Master/Default Value
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 newrelic.appname   PHP Application     PHP Application
```

Using FastCGI via spawn-fcgi.

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running PHP as Apache module, or maybe as CGI/FastCGI application ?

Comment: Oops, I meant to include that in the post - I am using FastCGI.

Comment: I happen to be using WordPress for most of my sites, so I am usin `ini_set('newrelic.appname', 'MySite.com')` in the `wp-config.php` file to more or less make this work, but I'm still not sure how to set php values in config using PHP/FastCGI.

Comment: .htaccess is an Apache thing. When you're using Apache's mod_php, it'd work, but FastCGI isn't hooked into Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use .htaccess configuration files while using PHP as CGI/FastCGI, you could use [htscanner PHP module](http://pecl.php.net/package/htscanner), which can parse existing and new .htaccess configuration files with various options (including php_value).

**UPDATE:** Answer is outdated.  See below for updated answer:

> Since PHP 5.3.0 PHP includes support for [configuration INI files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) on a per-directory
>   basis. These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. **This
>   functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner extension.** If you are using
>   Apache, use .htaccess files for the same effect.